# Getting pipeline running timestamp in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

How can I get the value of the following in DataFactory:

1. Last time the pipeline was triggered
2. Current starting time of the triggered pipeline

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no easy way. As far as I know, you cannot do that with just data factory, I'd run an Azure Function to look for that using PowerShell or Python's sdk.
2. This one is easy, you can get it using:

   "@trigger().startTime"

And that will give you the current starting time. Doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

You could get some of this messages in Data Factory `monitor/pipeline run` page:

[image]

It include: `last run time(triggered time)` and `DURACTION`.

But for now, we can not export it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you saying that there are no variables that contains these values? Or is there any way we can put this information into a variable?

Comment: @OreoFanatics  That's an overview page. But from the documents, you could set the pipeline parameter and using 'Add dynamic content' to add these [system variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables) with [Expressions and functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions).

Comment: From your screenshot, say I would like to compare the current pipeline (which is retrievable from @trigger().startTime) with the last running one (3/2/20, 3:02:17 PM). Can you retrieve that?

Comment: @OreoFanatics Sorry,  I can't.